# Custom permalink with dynamic rewrite tags on a Wordpress custom post type

Tags: wordpress, permalinks

I have a custom post type named `location` and I'm trying to set posts of this type as children of existing pages, to achieve a permalink structure like this:

```
example.com/alabama  <-- Page with generic content
example.com/alabama/locations  <-- Another page, child of a state page
example.com/alabama/locations/location-name  <- Custom type, child of alabama/locations seen above and titled `Location Name`
```

The closest I've got to create hierarchical relationships between two distinct post types was through a meta box where I can assign a post ID as the `post_parent` of my custom type posts when saving them. However despite the page ID being indeed saved to the CPT `post_parent` field, it has no effect on the permalinks. They are coming as defined in the `rewrite` CPT option. But I don't know how to make the `['rewrite']['slug']` option dynamic, or if it's even possible.

This is how my post type is being defined:

```
add_action( 'init', function() {
  register_post_type( 'location', [
    'label' => 'Location',
    'menu_icon' => 'dashicons-location-alt',
    'supports' => [ 'title', 'editor', 'custom-fields' ],
    'public' => true,
    'hierarchical' => false,
    'has_archive' => false,
    'rewrite' => false,
  ] );
} );
```

How can I configure the rewrite rules for locations to get the permalinks I need?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'm assuming that all the `location` posts will have a permalink structure that looks like this:

```
example.com/{STATE NAME}/locations/{CPT SLUG}
```

Sample URL addresses:

```
http://example.com/alabama/locations/location-1
http://example.com/alabama/locations/location-2
http://example.com/new-york/locations/location-3
```

---

So if that is correct, then:

• Use the `add_rewrite_rule()` function to add a custom rewrite rule for those permalinks.

• You don't need the `/locations/` Page.

```
add_action( 'init', function(){
    // Handles requests to `your-site-domain.com/{STATE NAME}/locations/{CPT SLUG}`
    add_rewrite_rule(
        '([^/]+)/locations/([^/]+)(?:/([0-9]+))?/?$',
        'index.php?location=$matches[2]&page=$matches[3]&state_name=$matches[1]',
        'top'
    );

    // Allows you to retrieve the `state_name`; for example using `get_query_var()`.
    add_rewrite_tag( '%state_name%', '([\w\-]+)' );
} );
```

*(You can change `state_name` to another name; it's up to you. And don't forget to flush the rewrite rules — go to the Permalink Settings page and click on the Save Changes button without having to make any changes.)*

---

Next, when you create or edit a `location` post, set the value of the `post_parent` custom field to the *ID* of the 'state Page' — e.g. the `/alabama/` Page.

And this code will filter the `get_permalink()` output, and returns the appropriate permalink for a `location` post:

```
add_filter( 'post_type_link', 'so51217355_post_type_link', 10, 2 );
function so51217355_post_type_link( $permalink, $post ) {
    if ( 'location' === $post->post_type ) {
        $page_id = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'post_parent', true );

        $state_name = ( is_numeric( $page_id ) && $page_id ) ?
            get_post_field( 'post_name', $page_id ) : null;

        // Make sure the post is associated to a valid 'state Page'.
        if ( $state_name ) {
            $permalink = $state_name . '/locations/' . $post->post_name;
            $permalink = home_url( user_trailingslashit( $permalink ) );
        }
    }

    return $permalink;
}
```

So for example, `get_permalink( 123 )` would return `http://example.com/alabama/locations/location-1`, if the `location` post's slug is `location-1`, and its 'state Page' is `/alabama/`.

---

### UPDATE

When the permalink is requested (i.e. users visit `example.com/{STATE NAME}/locations/{CPT SLUG}`), and you want to make sure the 'state Page' and `location` post both exist, *and* that the 'state Page' was indeed associated to the `location` post, then this code can help you:

```
// Validates the `state_name` of the current page/URL.
add_action( 'parse_request', 'so51217355_parse_request' );
function so51217355_parse_request( $wp ) {
    if ( ! empty( $wp->query_vars['state_name'] ) &&
        ! empty( $wp->query_vars['location'] ) ) {
        global $wpdb;

        $page_id = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare(
            "SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE post_name = %s",
            $wp->query_vars['state_name']
        ) );

        if ( ! is_numeric( $page_id ) || ! $page_id ) {
            $wp->query_vars['error'] = '404';

            // Don't let WordPress finds a post with nearest match.
            remove_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical' );

            return;
        }

        $post_id = $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare(
            "SELECT ID FROM {$wpdb->posts} WHERE post_name = %s",
            $wp->query_vars['location']
        ) );

        $page_id2 = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'post_parent', true );
        if ( (int) $page_id2 !== (int) $page_id ) {
            $wp->query_vars['error'] = '404';

            // Don't let WordPress finds a post with nearest match.
            remove_action( 'template_redirect', 'redirect_canonical' );
        }
    }
}
```

### UPDATE #2

*Refer to the `// Comment` in the code below this image — see the `_so51217355_admin_ajax_js()` function.*

[image]

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_so51217355_admin_ajax', '_so51217355_admin_ajax_php' );
function _so51217355_admin_ajax_php() {
    $post_id = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'post_id' );
    echo get_sample_permalink_html( $post_id );
    wp_die();
}

add_action( 'admin_print_footer_scripts', '_so51217355_admin_ajax_js', 11 );
function _so51217355_admin_ajax_js() {
    $screen = get_current_screen();
    if ( 'location' === $screen->id ) :
    ?>
<script>
// This script will sync the Permalink under the big/main post title box on
// the Edit Post page; but only if and when editing or deleting the custom
// field as in `meta_key` below. Make sure to change it, if necessary.
jQuery( function( $ ){
    var meta_key = 'post_parent';

    function ajax() {
        $.post( ajaxurl, {
            action: 'so51217355_admin_ajax',
            post_id: $( '#post_ID' ).val()
        }, function( s ){
            $( '#edit-slug-box' ).html( s );
        } );
    }

    function _go( e, a ) {
        var $input = $( a.target ),
            mid, mkey;

        if ( /^meta\-(\d+)\-submit$/.test( $input.attr( 'name' ) ) ||
            /^deletemeta\[(\d+)\]$/.test( $input.attr( 'name' ) ) ) {
            mid = RegExp.$1;
            mkey = $( 'input[name="meta[' + mid + '][key]"]' ).val();

            if ( meta_key === mkey ) {
                ajax();
            }
        }
    }

    $( '#the-list' )
        .on( 'wpListAddEnd', _go )
        .on( 'wpListDelEnd', _go );
} );
</script>
    <?php
    endif;
}
```

Comment: This looks very close to what I need but 
I still cant get the right permalink in the Edit post form. How should I set the `rewrite` option of the CPT?

Comment: I used the exact one as you used with the `register_post_type()` function. Try this: create a Page, set its slug to `paris`; then create a `location` post, and set its slug to `location-20180609`, and set its `post_parent` custom field value to the ID of the `paris` Page. Then check its permalink.

Comment: I've set `'rewrite' => false` and the permalink is showing up in the Edit form, but the page loads no matter what string I pass as state name. So I created the post `http://example.com/alabama/locations/location-1` and I can access it thru any url like `http://example.com/hello/locations/location-1` which is not good as I could potentially have multiple locations with same name on more than one state. Where can I validate it the state page id set in `wp_postmeta` matches the REQUEST_URI relevant part or some similar solution?

Comment: Please check the updated answer. (All the code would be in the theme's main `functions.php` file. But you can place them in another PHP file and `require` it from the `functions.php` file)

Comment: The **UPDATE #2** code is totally optional and you wouldn't want to use it if you're not using the standard Custom Fields editor in `wp-admin`.

Comment: Your help has been so valuable! Thanks so much for guiding me through this!